# What is decidability and completeness?

Tags: logic, incompleteness, decidability

A formal system comes with both a syntactic component, which determines the notion of provability ($\vdash$),
and a semantic component, which determines the notion of truth ($\vDash$).

For this question assume that we don't know if $\vdash$ and $\vDash$ are equivalent.

What is the well-accepted definition of decidability of a system? I'm confused between the following two:

1. Decidable if for any formula $F$, there exists an algorithm to determine if $F$ is true
2. Decidable if for any formula $F$, there exists an algorithm to determine if $F$ is provable

Similarly for completeness I'm assuming it is defined as:

1. Complete, if for every $F$, if $\vDash F$ then $\vdash F$

Comment: Completeness: correct.

Comment: Decidability: both. For sistems based on first.order logic, that is complete, the two are equivalent.

Comment: See e.g. Enderton's [Logic](https://www.google.it/books/edition/A_Mathematical_Introduction_to_Logic/dVncCl_EtUkC), page 142-145 for *decidability*: "Let $\Gamma$ be a decidable set of formulas in a reasonable language. Then, the set of theorems of $\Gamma$ is effectively enumerable, and the set $\{ \varphi \mid \Gamma \vDash \varphi \}$ of formulas logically implied by $\Gamma$ is effectively enumerable. [...] It should be remarked that our proofs of enumerability cannot, in general, be strengthened to proofs of decidability. For almost all languages the set of validities is not decidable."

Comment: And page 131: "SOUNDNESS TH. If $\Gamma \vdash \varphi$, then $\Gamma \vDash \varphi$", and page 135: "COMPLETENESS TH. (a) If $\Gamma \vDash \varphi$, then $\Gamma \vdash \varphi$. (b) Any *consistent* set of formulas is *satisfiable*."

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thank you, I'll check out the reference